# How do I embed a UITableView in a UIView?

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview, uiview, embed

I have a `UIView` in a custom view that I built using `xib`. I need to display a `UITableView` in the said view. At first I thought about placing a `container` and embedding a `UITableViewController` in it. Turns out I cannot place `containers` in a `xib` file, or atleast there's no way of doing it from the `IB` as it doesn't show up in views section at the lower right.

I can create a `UITableView` programmatically and add it as a subview of the view. It shows up as expected but I cannot seem to be able to add cells in it. I also tried creating a well behaving `UITableViewController` in association with a `storyboard` view, instantiate that controller as follows:

`let storyboard = (UIStoryboard(name: "Main", bundle: nil))
let vc = storyboard.instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier("tableViewController") as! TestTableViewController`

and then tried accessing the `UITableView`'s outlet which was `nil`. Then I read somewhere that I should do a `vc.loadView()` because as the name suggests, it loads the view and my `IBOutlet` would not be `nil`. This worked. The outlet was on longer `nil`. But, when I add the table in the container view as a subview, it still shows no cells. There are only separator lines but no content. I've run out of ideas!

**EDIT**

I do not have any `UITableViewCell` implementations as the tables are static.

Answer (score 3):

Good approach is to use UITableview inside your custom view:

if you are adding tableview programmatically then register your cell using Nib or UITableview subclass like

```
tableView.registerNib(UINib(nibName: "UITableViewCellSubclass", bundle: nil), forCellReuseIdentifier: "UITableViewCellSubclass")
```

for if you are creating UITableviewCell using Xib.

```
tableView.registerClass(UITableViewCellSubclass.self, forCellReuseIdentifier: "UITableViewCellSubclass") // using code.
tableView.delegate = self
tableView.dataSource = self
```

and then use 2 required delegates.

```
func tableView(tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
return 2 
}

func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
return tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("UITableViewCellSubclass", forIndexPath: indexPath) as! UITableViewCellSubclass
}
```

hope i answered your question.

Comment: if it makes any difference, the table is static. its contents remain the same.

Comment: actually i forgot to mention, I have no UITableViewCell implementations as my tables are static

Answer (score 0):

Objective c
You need delegates in your viewcontroller, if you have a viewcontroller, put delegate of table :

UIViewController 
UITableViewDelegate 
UITableViewDataSource

And you can use your functions

```
    - (NSInteger)numberOfSectionsInTableView:(UITableView *)tableView
{
    return 1;    //count of section
}


- (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section {

    return [catagorry count];    //count number of row from counting array hear cataGorry is An Array
}



- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView
             cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
    {
        static NSString *MyIdentifier = @"MyIdentifier";

        UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:MyIdentifier];

        if (cell == nil)
        {
            cell = [[[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault
                                           reuseIdentifier:MyIdentifier] autorelease];
        }

        // Here we use the provided setImageWithURL: method to load the web image
        // Ensure you use a placeholder image otherwise cells will be initialized with no image
        [cell.imageView setImageWithURL:[NSURL URLWithString:@"http://example.com/image.jpg"]
                       placeholderImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"placeholder"]];
            cell.textLabel.text = @"My Text";
        return cell;
    }
```

Swift :

delegate: 
UIViewController 
UITableViewDataSource
UITableViewDelegate

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    tableView.delegate = self
    tableView.dataSource = self
}
```

Swift

```
func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
    let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier(textCellIdentifier, forIndexPath: indexPath)

    let row = indexPath.row
    cell.textLabel?.text = swiftBlogs[row]

    return cell
}

func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
    let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier(textCellIdentifier, forIndexPath: indexPath)

    let row = indexPath.row
    cell.textLabel?.text = swiftBlogs[row]

    return cell
}


func tableView(tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
    return swiftBlogs.count
}


func numberOfSectionsInTableView(tableView: UITableView) -> Int {
    return 1
}
```

Look more [More inf](http://www.codingexplorer.com/getting-started-uitableview-swift/)